# How to merge output of child step functions into parent step function output

Tags: aws-step-functions

AWS has given the following link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/orchestrating-aws-glue-crawlers-using-aws-step-functions/ to Orchestrate Glue Crawlers using Map state. I used this example, and it works great. But I'm, not able to read output of each crawler execution from the parent step function. The SUCCESS state of parent step function only shows 1 crawler execution result. Each child crawler individually shows its own execution result. But how do we get the execution result of each child crawler from the parent step function? What changes do we need to make to the above example? What settings need to change? Please help

Answer (score 0):

That example sets ResultPath to `null` for the Map state that runs the set of crawlers. This instructs Step Functions to disregard the output of the Map State itself which is why the output of the Execution is the list of crawlers, which was the input to the Map state.

If you want to have access to the output from each crawler run, you can just remove the ResultPath attribute from the Map state. You will then get an output something like what I have below. Keep in mind in this case that if the number crawlers that match the tag you provided is large enough, this could lead to the Map state's output exceeding the 256 kB state payload limit for Step Functions. In which case, you might want to do something in the ItemProcessor of the Map state to pass on only what data you really need.

```
[
  {
    "ExecutionArn": "arn:aws:states:us-west-2:123456789012:execution:demo-manage-glue-with-stepfunctions_run-crawler:0a1ffc7b-eee2-4842-a840-1686a2d64e0b",
    "Input": {
      "crawler_name": "demo-manage-glue-with-stepfunctions-all-time-location-summaries"
    },
    "InputDetails": {
      "Included": true
    },
    "Name": "0a1ffc7b-eee2-4842-a840-1686a2d64e0b",
    "Output": {
      "LastCrawl": {
        "LogGroup": "/aws-glue/crawlers",
        "LogStream": "demo-manage-glue-with-stepfunctions-all-time-location-summaries",
        "MessagePrefix": "e1caa570-7bfe-4bbd-821a-e599994a1d32",
        "StartTime": "2023-09-04T19:18:58Z",
        "Status": "SUCCEEDED"
      },
      "crawler_name": "demo-manage-glue-with-stepfunctions-all-time-location-summaries"
    },
    "OutputDetails": {
      "Included": true
    },
    "StartDate": 1693855138497,
    "StateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-west-2:123456789012:stateMachine:demo-manage-glue-with-stepfunctions_run-crawler",
    "Status": "SUCCEEDED",
    "StopDate": 1693855375497
  },
  {
    "ExecutionArn": "arn:aws:states:us-west-2:123456789012:execution:demo-manage-glue-with-stepfunctions_run-crawler:45e64e45-6100-41f3-b91a-b6499f93127c",
    "Input": {
      "crawler_name": "demo-manage-glue-with-stepfunctions-daily-location-summaries"
    },
    "InputDetails": {
      "Included": true
    },
    "Name": "45e64e45-6100-41f3-b91a-b6499f93127c",
    "Output": {
      "LastCrawl": {
        "LogGroup": "/aws-glue/crawlers",
        "LogStream": "demo-manage-glue-with-stepfunctions-daily-location-summaries",
        "MessagePrefix": "680ae84c-63c2-4401-9d58-f325aa1d7776",
        "StartTime": "2023-09-04T19:18:58Z",
        "Status": "SUCCEEDED"
      },
      "crawler_name": "demo-manage-glue-with-stepfunctions-daily-location-summaries"
    },
    "OutputDetails": {
      "Included": true
    },
    "StartDate": 1693855138475,
    "StateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-west-2:123456789012:stateMachine:demo-manage-glue-with-stepfunctions_run-crawler",
    "Status": "SUCCEEDED",
    "StopDate": 1693855500176
  },
  {
    "ExecutionArn": "arn:aws:states:us-west-2:123456789012:execution:demo-manage-glue-with-stepfunctions_run-crawler:0913e23a-1239-43d4-968a-c731bdae8e91",
    "Input": {
      "crawler_name": "demo-manage-glue-with-stepfunctions-daily-user-summaries"
    },
    "InputDetails": {
      "Included": true
    },
    "Name": "0913e23a-1239-43d4-968a-c731bdae8e91",
    "Output": {
      "LastCrawl": {
        "LogGroup": "/aws-glue/crawlers",
        "LogStream": "demo-manage-glue-with-stepfunctions-daily-user-summaries",
        "MessagePrefix": "e135da73-e6d9-4348-bbd4-0f3e03413e57",
        "StartTime": "2023-09-04T19:18:58Z",
        "Status": "SUCCEEDED"
      },
      "crawler_name": "demo-manage-glue-with-stepfunctions-daily-user-summaries"
    },
    "OutputDetails": {
      "Included": true
    },
    "StartDate": 1693855138472,
    "StateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-west-2:123456789012:stateMachine:demo-manage-glue-with-stepfunctions_run-crawler",
    "Status": "SUCCEEDED",
    "StopDate": 1693855437189
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. This certainly helped me understand what I should be looking for. In addition, I used method shown in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html to get the final output from all crawlers in an array form. Is this right, or is there a better way?